# CSS: Is it possible to add a footer to the page without a wrapper DIV?

Tags: html, css

I've searched the internet a lot to see if there's a neat, CSS-only way to show a footer at the bottom of the page (even if there's no or little content on it) and all of the solutions I've found are similar: Using a wrapper DIV with 100% height. Is it possible to achive a similar result without using the `#wrapper` DIV?

Comment: Sure, use absolute-positioning.

Comment: I thought the same but the footer is supposed to appear only at the end of the site.. So you might never know the height of the webpage if the contents are a little dynamic..

Comment: Yes, I'm completely with Ajai on this. I tried absolute positioning but it's not the correct way. (I think)

Comment: #footer {position:absolute; bottom:0;} ???

Comment: Do you mean a [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)?

Comment: ...if so, [yes it's possible](http://jsfiddle.net/XC9yY/) assuming you have the footer contained in an element. The catch is that it requires that the footer is a static height.

Comment: No, as much as the sticky header (like a menu) is fine, I don't think a sticky footer is a good design concept. I want a footer that is shown always at the end of the page.

Comment: `#footer { bottom: 0; left: 0; position: fixed; width: 100%; }` is all you need to stick the footer at the bottom of the page, however you'd also want to make sure you've got some padding at the end of your page so that it doesn't hide content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for not seeing your comment about not wanting sticky footers. They were hidden.

Anyway, it is possible to achieve this without wrappers. The CSS attributes you would give the wrapper are valid on the body as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/wffs8/8/

This works even if you do not have enough content to fill the screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/wffs8/9/